# Cocoa Memory Issue, Memory doesn't get reclaimed when objects are removed from array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, osx-lion

I have a retain/release project that has a simple algorithm. I start out w/ a 100000 objects mutable array and every 5 seconds interval I remove 1000 objects at the beginning and add 1000 objects at the end. In theory my memory footprint should stay the same after a lil delay, however it consistently rises until it caps out at a certain amount. But removing all its objects with "[array removeAllObjects]" and releasing the array doesn't reclaim all the memory back, just a portion. I am running in release scheme, with no debugger, and using the activity monitor to track memory usage.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0; i<100000; i++){
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];
        [array addObject:url];
    }
    self.t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10  target:self selector:@selector(addAndRemove:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

}

```
-(IBAction)addAndRemove:(id)sender{
     [array removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1000)];

     for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++){
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];
        [array addObject:url];
     }
}

-(IBAction)clear:(id)sender {
    [array removeAllObjects];    
    [array release];
    [t invalidate];
    t = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monitoring your memory usage with Activity Monitor is pretty unreliable.  First, which memory field are you watching (Virtual Private Memory, Real Private Memory, Real Shared Memory, or Real Memory)?

Second, when your code makes an allocation request, that typically goes, directly or indirectly, to the malloc routines.  The malloc routines try to satisfy your request from the memory that it already has.  If it can't then it requests more from the system.  When you free memory, it goes back to malloc.  Malloc does not necessarily return it to the system.  It may keep it to more quickly satisfy future requests.  So, you may not see your process's memory usage go down, at least not all the way, even if your program is releasing everything it allocated.

The proper way to check that your program is managing memory correctly is to use Instruments with the Leaks and Allocations tools.

Comment: I'd make a strong statement;  monitoring memory usage with AM is outright useless save for catching runaway growth.

Comment: I'm looking at real memory size. I already used the leaks instrument and there aren't any memory leaks. What should I look for when i'm using the Allocation tool?

Comment: I did a test in the allocation instrument and it behaved correctly. Activity Monitor is just highly inaccurate like you guys said.

Comment: @Ken For 'Malloc does not necessarily return it to the system.'.  Do you have any references about this behavior?

Comment: @teerapap No specific references off-hand. It's widely known and maybe a web search will find it for you. It's also inherent in how `malloc()` works vs. how allocations from the system VM via `vm_allocate()` works. `malloc()` allows for allocations of any size. `vm_allocate()` allocates a page (see `getpagesize()`) at a time. So, if you `malloc()` a bunch of small buffers, they are likely to all come from the same page, which is one allocation from system memory. If you then free some of them, the space can't be returned to the system because parts of it are still in use.

Answer (score 3):

When you create your NSURL using

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];
```

You are creating an Autoreleased object. Autoreleased objects get stored in the autorelease pool and are only destroyed when that pool is emptied. The main pool is flushed every 60th of a second when the main run loop fires, so maybe your objects are being released later than you expect them to be.

Try wrapping your for loops in an @autoreleasepool { } block so that any autoreleased objects created inside the loop are flushed immediately, or alternatively create your NSURL using alloc/init so that it's not autoreleased, e.g.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];
```

Then see if that changes your memory usage.

Comment: The main pool does not get “flushed every 60th of a second”; the application object drains its pool and replaces it with a new one every time the application processes an event. (And yes, this can bite long-running background applications.) Moreover, it's better to inform your memory optimization using Instruments rather than taking blind stabs at random lines of code.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting this as an memory optimisation strategy, but rather as a possible explanation for why the memory wasn't being released when the array was destroyed. I accept that Ken's answer seems more likely however.